# Inverse transform sampling of $f(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda (x-a)}$

Tags: statistics

I have the following problem:

Given the PDF $$f(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda (x-a)}$$ find the CDF through inverse transform sampling.

My question is, with respect to what variable should I integrate. I've seen that it can be from some $a$ to $x$ or from $0$ to $x$. And, if it is from $a$ to $x$, do I need something like an $a'$ ? The answers say it's $F(x)=\frac{\log(1-x)-\lambda a}{-\lambda}$ but I think this is not correct.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first rule about densities is that they have to integrate to $1$. So in order for $\int f(x)dx$ to equal $1$, the density will be $\lambda e^{-\lambda(x-a)}$ for $x>a$, and is zero otherwise. The CDF is then, for $x>a$,
$$F(x):=\int_{-\infty}^x f(t)\,dt=\int_a^x \lambda e^{-\lambda(t-a)}\,dt$$
which you can evaluate using the change of variables $u:=t-a$. You then invert the equation $y=F(x)$ to obtain $x=F^{-1}(y)$ as a function of $y$. This gives the inverse CDF. BTW, the answer is correct: I get $x$ as the following function of $y$:
$$F^{-1}(y) = a - \frac{\log(1-y)}\lambda$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think now I'm getting it. The limits of integration depend on the function, so if I get a function like $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$, the CDF will be for $x > 0$. In my case, since it had the exponential function, thus the $x > a$.

Comment: Right, the limits of integration depend on the function. But if your function is $f(x):=\frac1{1+x^2}$, then (1) this is not a density, and (2) it's defined for all $x$, not just $x>0$.